# Terminal and annual surplus distribution in participating life insurance

Tags: asset-pricing, surplus

I consider a participating life insurance contract which is fair if $P_0 = e^{-rT} \mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}}\left[ L(T) \right)$ ($\mathbb{Q}$ denotes the risk-neutral measure), where $P_0$ is the premium and $L(T)$ the claims paid by the insurance company. $L(T)$ is given by:
$$ L(T) = P(T) + \delta B(T) - D(T), $$ with 
$$P(t) = P(t-1) (1+g) + \max \left( \alpha \gamma (A(t) - A(t-1))-g P(t-1),0\right),$$ 
$$B(T) = \max\left(\frac{P_0}{A_0} A(T) - P(T),0\right),$$
$$ D(T) = \max\left( P(T) - A(T),0\right).$$ 
$g$ is the guaranteed minimum interest rate, $\delta$ the terminal surplus participation rate, $\alpha$ the annual surplus rate, and $\gamma \in (0,1)$. The asset $A$ follows a geometric brownian motion:
$$A(T) = A(0) \exp\left( (r-\sigma^2/2)T + \sigma W_T^{\mathbb{Q}}\right).$$ 
Does it make sense to consider a terminal or an annual surplus rate larger than 100%? An annual rate larger than 100% leads to a decrease in reserves for the insurance company, in my opinion this is not a realistic distribution rule, right? But what about the terminal surplus rate?